# Computer Challenge Puzzle? Table with numbers and 2^x

Tags: puzzle

I know this is kind of a vague question, but I'm doing a computer-style puzzle and am completely lost on this one.  It gives a display of a table of these numbers:

[image]

And asks for a keyword from those numbers.  Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What is the computer challenge puzzle question? What does that image file have to do with the puzzle? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: That's the thing.  The only hint/thing I have to work with for the puzzle is the table in that image.  There is no question other than finding a keyword from that table (somehow), but it gives no hints on how to do so.  Sorry if it's unclear, it's just really out of nowhere for a computer puzzle :D

Comment: I think you should ask this on: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ seeing as we have nothing to go on.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the reference, logic!  I'll post there and see if anyone can figure this guy out :)  Thanks again!

Comment: It's interesting... I suspect your answer will be in ASCII, and the numbers at the top indicate that each row is 1 byte in binary code (128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)

Comment: When you say one byte in binary, do you mean that the numbers under 2^7 would all be one bit in a binary number for ASCII?

Comment: Each row is one byte. Binary counts from right to left. The eighth digit (rightmost) represents either 0 or 1 (2^0), the 2nd is either 0 or 2 (2^1), then 0 or 4  (2^2) etc. up to the 8th being either 0 or 256 (2^7)

Comment: So the first byte (row) looks like this when converted as described in the answer: 01101001 < Add all that up and you get 105. 105 is the ASCII code for the letter `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The numbers at the top are a clue, telling you the answer is in binary.
If you treat each odd number as a 0, and each even number as 1, then the binary is:

01101001
00111100
00110011
01101101
01100001
01110100
01101000
00100001

which translates to: `i<3math!`